# C++ Program crash when calling function from address

Tags: c++, function, memory

```
void print()
{
  printf("Test");
}
```

This does not work

> Unhandled exception at 0x00402826 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x00000000.

```
int main()
{
  typedef void function(void);
  function* Execute = (function*)0x00402810;
  Execute();
}
```

But this works?

```
int main()
{
  void(*func)();
  func = &print;
  cout << func;
  getchar();

  typedef void function(void);
  function* Execute = (function*)0x00402810;
  Execute();
 }
```

I am compiling with /Dynamicbase:NO

so addresses are static on every run.

Comment: Have you tried using `typedef void(function*)();` instead of `typedef void function(void)`?

Comment: How can you guarantee that your function actually starts at 0x402810? You cannot! The compiler can move your functions around as it likes.

Comment: Yes it does, it works on the code below.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that when you declare print() before main() it is actually compiled to a few addresses before main() (As one might expect). From here, since the main() function on your second example is not the same as the first one (larger), the address of the print() function might have changed between the two examples.

If you really want to find out the address of your function i'd recommend using a debugger to find that out.

Hope it helps.